# How to Customize the width of camera in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created one application in xamarin forms to open the camera in video mode only(using Media plugin).What I want to reduce the width of the camera so that I can place one button at the bottom.

In MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="10">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button x:Name="takeVideo" IsVisible="False" Text="Take Video"/>
        <Image x:Name="image" WidthRequest="72" Aspect="Fill"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public void OpenCamera()
    {
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
        {
            DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var file = CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
        {
            Name = "video.mp4",
            Directory = "DefaultVideos",

        });

        if (file == null)
            return;      
    }
```

Comment: You cannot do this with the media plugin

Comment: Can you tell me then how to create then custom camera preview from where i can take video and also able to place button by reducing the width of camera?

Comment: Use [Camera2 for Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/Camera2Basic/) and [AVFoundation](https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-camera-display-avfoundation/) in iOS

Comment: That Camera2 for Android Sample is for taking the photo.That i have seen already. But not getting any Sample for taking the video.

Comment: Even for taking a Video Camera2 is used you just call a different API of camera2